# Finding duplicate entries in any of several columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have code that identifies potential duplicate records based on the fact that several rows (with different IDs) have the same value in various other columns. This info gets manually reviewed, so I am not worried about the fact that a husband and wife could legitimately share an email address, for example. An example of the query I am using is this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID, Email 
FROM Customers 
WHERE Email IS NOT NULL AND Email != '' AND Email IN
    (SELECT Email FROM Customers GROUP BY Email HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ID) > 1) 
ORDER BY Email;
```

Which gives me results like this:

```
ID       Email
108      bob@hotmail.com
381      bob@hotmail.com
205      mary@gmail.com
772      mary@gmail.com
908      mary@gmail.com
```

This works great for my purposes, except when I try matching by phone number, which has multiple columns (HomePhone, BusinessPhone, CellPhone).  This creates two problems - the first, which has been pretty well documented on this forum, is how to identify rows in which any of three columns contain a matching value (If a value in [row 1 column A, B, or C] matches a column in [row 2 column A, B, or C] then I want to select both rows).  The second problem, which I haven't figured out yet and haven't found an answer to, is how to select [ID], [Value that Matched] as my output.

I suppose that I could select all three columns and do some further code magic in my program to make sense of it, but that prevents me from reusing existing code and also seems like the type of hack that a developer would use to keep from admitting that he needs help from a DBA.  (Help!)  In all seriousness, though, I am stuck trying to find an elegant solution, and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you show some sample data and the expected result for phone number mismatches?

Comment: @RyanVincent - I agree with this in terms of database normalization, but in this case I'm working with the tables I inherited...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this with `apply`:

```
select c.*, phone
from (select c.*, count(*) over (partition by phone) as cnt
      from customers c cross apply
           (select distinct v.phone
            from (values (homephone), (businessphone), (cellphone)
                 ) v(phone)
            where v.phone is not null
           ) v(phone)
     ) c
where cnt > 1
order by phone;
```

The innermost subquery selects the distinct phones for each customer.  The `count(*) over . . .` then counts the number of times that the `phone` appears (which because of the distinct is for different customers).  The final `where` chooses phones that appear for multiple customers.

Comment: I had to tweak this slightly, but this pointed me in the right direction and is surprisingly efficient!  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Based on my understanding of the question,

You can initially use `union all` and get the different phone numbers into one column and `group by` that column to see if there are duplicates. Thereafter, `join` on the original table to get the customer id.

```
with cnts as (
      select phone 
      from (select id,homephone phone from customers
            union all
            select id,businessphone from customers
            union all
            select id,cellphone from customers) x
      group by phone
      having count(distinct id) > 1
    )
select c.id,cn.phone value_matched
from customers c
join cnts cn on cn.phone in (c.homephone,c.businessphone,c.cellphone)     
order by 1,2
```

Comment: +1 for a correct output and an elegant solution, but after testing both, it looks like the cross apply works significantly faster, so I'm awarding the correct answer to Gordon.  Thank you for your answer, though!

Comment: `homephone phone ` there is an extra phone or you want add another field?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza .. phone is a column alias here :)

Comment: ohh my bad, but that is why you should use `AS` ;)

Comment: sure..i will from here on.